# Installation Requirements to Setup PCF on a Local Server

Tags: cloud-foundry

Do you have recommendations to where can I read a good reference on what are the hardware and software requirements, as well as installation procedures of Pivotal Cloud Foundry(not the PCF dev)  on a local server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Links below will get you started.

For PCF on vSphere
http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-8/customizing/vsphere.html

For PCF on Azure
http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-8/customizing/azure.html

For PCF on AWS
http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-8/customizing/cloudform.html

For PCF on GCP
http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-8/customizing/gcp.html

Installing PCF depends on lot of factors. But this is good for an out of the box installation.

Answer (score 0):

PCF is a distributed system, and not designed to be run on a single server. Why do you want to do this? It will not be covered by whatever support agreement you have in place.

PCF Dev is the solution for experimenting with PCF - you can use it as an answer to the question "what is the minimum I need to run PCF", with regards to minimal components and tech specs.